# "Внимание" или "внимания"? Какой падеж будет у слова в приведенном предложении? Допустимы ли оба варианта? Какой предпочтительней?

Tags: падежи

*Маша даже постучала пальцами по столу, но **внимание** соседа все равно не привлекла.*
Это случай с переходным глаголом с отрицанием? Влияет ли порядок слов в предложении на написание слова "внимание"? То есть если оно будет следовать за "не привлекла"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы в данном случае выбрала В.п.:

*Маша даже постучала пальцами по столу, но **внимание** соседа все равно не привлекла.*

Здесь возможно влияние двух факторов: (1) Р.п. при выражении дополнения отвлеченными существительными, (2) В.п. нередко при инверсии дополнения.

Соответственно, допустимы оба падежа, авторский выбор.

Во втором варианте при **инверсии и дистантном** расположении дополнения **влияние отрицания ослабляется**, что характерно для В.п.

Розенталь, [§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием.](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04)